# System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Speech.dll

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I recive this error 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Speech.dll ' and yes I read all questions about this error, but any can fixed my error, please help me, I have the next code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    String speech;
    SpeechRecognitionEngine reconocedor = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    SpeechSynthesizer AVJarvis = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AVJarvis.Speak("Iniciando");
        AVJarvis.Speak("Buenos días Kevin");
        CargarGramatica();
    }

    void CargarGramatica()
    {
        reconocedor.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines("ComandosDefecto.txt"))))); //Cargo los comandos del .txt
        //reconocedor.LoadGrammarAsync(new DictationGrammar()); //Carga todas las gramaticas de mi sistema
        reconocedor.SpeechRecognized += reconocedor_SpeechRecognized;
        reconocedor.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        reconocedor.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    }

    void reconocedor_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        speech = e.Result.Text;

        switch (speech)
        {

            case "Buenos días Asistente":
                AVJarvis.Speak("Buenos días Kevin");
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

}[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Krz.png)

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Did you run it as an admin?

Comment: In this line  reconocedor.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines("ComandosDefecto.txt")))));

And yes I run it as an admin

Comment: And now say "No recognizer installed" why? Mi microphone works correctly.